# How do I combine TypeScript Object/Record typing, code completion and VSCode "Go to Definition" feature?

Tags: typescript, react-native, linear-gradients, native-base

I am combining [react native, native base and linear gradients](https://docs.nativebase.io/box#h3-with-linear-gradient) which looks something like this:

```js
<Box
  bg={{
    linearGradient: {
      colors: ['lightBlue.300', 'violet.800'],
      start: [0, 0],
      end: [1, 0],
    },
  }}
/>
```

Native base exports this type as `ILinearGradientProps`. My application includes 15+ linear gradients which need to be accessed in different components. I added a `LinearGradients` object which looks something like this but with actual props filled in (colors, start, end):

```js
import { ILinearGradientProps } from 'native-base';

type LGKey = 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'success' | ...;

export const LinearGradients: Record<LGKey, ILinearGradientProps> = {
  primary: { ...linearGradientProps },
  secondary: { ...linearGradientProps },
  success: { ...linearGradientProps },
  ...
```

With the above typing `Record<LGKey, ILinearGradientProps>`:

- the type is correct
- there is code completion when defining `LinearGradients` properties
- there is also code completion when accessing `LinearGradients` properties on a component, eg. `<Box bg={LinearGradients.pri`

However, using `Ctrl/Cmd + Click` or the "Go to Definition" feature from VSCode (and maybe other code editors too) directly on the property `LinearGradients.primary` does not work. It would be good if VSCode could direct me to the specific property within `LinearGradients`.

If I change the code to like below, the go to definition feature works but it doesn't seem like good TS code IMO:

```
export const LinearGradients = {
  primary: { ...linearGradientProps } as ILinearGradientProps,
  secondary: { ...linearGradientProps } as ILinearGradientProps,
  success: { ...linearGradientProps } as ILinearGradientProps,
  ...
```

Does anyone know how I can have all four of these features working together (without asserting the type for every new property with `as` like above) to achieve:

- safe/correct typing
- code completion when defining `LinearGradients` properties
- code completion when accessing `LinearGradients` properties
- Go to Definition feature on VSCode

or is this just a limitation of TypeScript right now?

This has come up for me a few times now and I cannot find much about this online, so would really appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// ts@>=4.9
export const LinearGradients = {
  primary: { ...linearGradientProps },
  secondary: { ...linearGradientProps },
  success: { ...linearGradientProps },
} satisfies Record<LGKey, ILinearGradientProps>
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator